# How to intergrate Socket.Io in Laravel view

Tags: sockets, laravel, express, socket.io

I currently developing chat function in Laravel using socket.io.So I try to intergrated in blade view but I get this erros.

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   'D:\xampp\htdocs\FreelancerJob\public\chat\resources\views\ui\Chat\chat.blade.php'
>   at Error (native)

Here is my js file

```
var app=require('express')();
var http=require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/message',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/resources/views/ui/Chat/chat.blade.php");
});

http.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: Does `D:\xampp\htdocs\FreelancerJob\public\chat\resources\views\ui\Chat\chat.blade.php` exist on your system? How are you running the php file through blade and laravel?

Comment: @bolav i try to intergrate in blade view is that ok ?
and my dir is D:\xampp\htdocs\FreelancerJob\resources\views\ui\Chat

Comment: There is no blade rendering engine for node.js / express, and if you just use `sendFile`, you will just be sending raw (un-executed) php to the client.

Comment: @AshleyB do you have any suggest about my case ?

Comment: I don't know much about how Laravel uses socket.io, but I would have thought you would need to render your blade template using Laravel. Why do you need to render it using node.js?